# Obtener valor de un input type="text" C# MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mvc

Buenas noches a todos.

Estoy diseñando una pagina web usando MVC, C# y HTML. Diseñe un formulario para realizar un alta pero en dicho formulario hay un dato a cargar que no es ingresado por el usuario sino que en base a un dato anterior que el usuario si carga éste dato es calculado automaticamente. Los problemas son dos:

1º) Como obtengo el dato que el usuario ingreso en un input=text y lo guardo en una variable para luego usarlo para calcular el valor que necesito se calcule automaticamente.

2º) Una vez que pueda obtener el dato ingresado en el input tengo que usarlo para hacer una consulta sql de manera de obtener el dato que necesito. Esta consulta sql donde debe ir? En que capa (Modelo vista o controlador?)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Estimado la respuesta a su pregunta requiere demasiada explicación, tienes dudas con aspectos más básicos del MVC, te recomiendo leer una guía, además visual studio cuenta con plantillas que hacen exactamente lo que quieres, ahí podrás revisar el código y ver como se hace,

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Workshop recomendado. Es un resumen de 4 horas de un curso de 27 horas aproximadamente de lo que en su tiempo fue la Microsoft Virtual Academy. Saludos.